# Google Play Service library in Android

Tags: android, google-play-services

Hello I am trying to use `google-play-services_lib` in my android project. As you know in android phone there is Google Play Service APK which provide a some features to you such as location fetching etc.

So I have confusion that Suppose user have Google Play Service APK version is 4.3 and I am using Google Play Services library version is 4.0.30 in android project to build the app.

Do we require same version on both side like build with same latest Google play service library and Google Play Services installed APK to make as like Push Notification, Location fetching work in this case or there is no link between them ?

[image]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They don't have to match.

The development of the library and the application is not completely dependant, that's why thier version number is different. As far as I know, each release of the services apk defines a maximum version of the library that is supported. So the only conflict could happen when the services apk is outdated (on the target device), and your application's library is a newer one.

The best you can do is to update the library, and the services application on your device.

It should work that way.

Comment: +1 Thanks but "As far as I know, each release of the services apk defines a maximum version of the library that is supported" ---- How can I know this information ?

Comment: Well, I don't know any clean method, but you can remove the "com.google.android.gms.version" metadata from the manifest, and this will cause a RuntimeException saying something like this: "The meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value.  Expected 4242000 but found 0.". I guess 4242000 is the maximum supported version in this case:)

Comment: what about they say the libraries are automatically updated

Answer (score 0):

I dont think so that there is link between APK and supported libraries in that because the APK silently gets updated about libraries